# Cannot get data as JSON from a PHP file on the server

Tags: javascript, php, json, phpmyadmin, xmlhttprequest

I have a database on the server, containing a table `customers`, and column `names` in that. I want to make a request to the server where I ask for the first 2 records in the `customers` table. Once I run the program, the browsers cannot display the records, it shows undefined. Look the image below.

[image]

.php:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);

$conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "abc", "def", "mydatabase");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT names FROM " . $obj->table . " LIMIT " . $obj->limit);
$outp = array();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

.html:

```
    <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
obj = { "table":"customers", "limit":2 };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (x in myObj) {
            txt += myObj[x].name + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "demo_file.php?x=" + dbParam, true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
```

Comment: Check your browser's developer console for the response details of the Ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be use `names` instead of `name` of object in loop in js because in your select query you have `names` columns and results have `names` property.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
    obj = { "table":"customers", "limit":2 };
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(myObj)
            for (x in myObj) {
                txt += myObj[x].names + "<br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "demo_file.php?x=" + dbParam, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

</script>
```

Comment: Hamedani, you Rocks! Simple mistake, I could not detect that. Thanks its working now.